# Coldfusion and java encryption functions

Tags: java, encryption, coldfusion

while trying to translate token generator for uservoice from java to coldfusion, I noticed the the hash function in java does the one in coldfusion :

```
String salted = "63bfb29835aedc55aae944e7cc9a202dmbdevsite";
byte[] hash = DigestUtils.sha(salted);
```

gives = [-19, -18, 7, 92, -121, 13, 88, 68, -84, 61, -77, -20, -85, -102, -102, -62, -70, 45, -16, 18]

```
<cfset Salted="63bfb29835aedc55aae944e7cc9a202dmbdevsite" />
<cfset hash=Hash(Salted,"SHA") />
<cfset arrBytes = hash.GetBytes() />
```

gives = 69686969485553675655486853565252656751686651696765665765576567506665506870484950

Can anyone explain this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use BinaryDecode to get the same byte array as the Java Hash.

```
<cfset Salted="63bfb29835aedc55aae944e7cc9a202dmbdevsite" />
<cfset hash = Hash(Salted,"SHA") />
<cfset arrBytes = BinaryDecode(hash, "hex") />
```

Answer (score 5):

You are actually getting the same result, however the outputs are encoded differently. For Java it's a byte array, and it's important to note that `byte` is signed. For ColdFusion you're getting hex that for some reason is outputted in decimal format for each hex character. If you look at http://asciitable.com/ and map the decimal numbers to their characters (e.g. 69 to E, 68 to D, 48 to 0), you get:

```
EDEE075C870D5844AC3DB3ECAB9A9AC2BA2DF012
```

Hashed results are often stored as hex. If you encode the Java version into hex, you'll get the same:

```
byte[] bytes = { -19, -18, 7, 92, -121, 13, 88, 68, -84, 61, -77, -20,
        -85, -102, -102, -62, -70, 45, -16, 18 };

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(2 * hash.length);
for (byte b : hash) {
    sb.append("0123456789ABCDEF".charAt((b & 0xF0) >> 4));
    sb.append("0123456789ABCDEF".charAt((b & 0x0F)));
}
String hex = sb.toString();
System.out.println(hex);
```

Comment: thanks, that's very clear, but i need this function in coldfusion 'caus i have the functionning code sheet written in java, and i want to translate to CF.

Comment: No problem. Your question only asks for an explanation and not a CF solution :) I don't know CF though, so I can't offer too much there. It looks like you'll have to decode the hex back into a signed byte array if you want the same result as Java.

Comment: Okay, will try to find function that do.